# Implication about the existence of f'(x)

Tags: derivatives, finite-differences

Let $h>0$. Consider the finite difference formula
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} \approx f'(x)
$$
which is called central difference. It is well known that for a sufficiently smooth function $f(x)$,

$$ \Bigg|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}-f'(x)\Bigg| = \mathcal{O}(h^2) $$

I have the following question: If

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} $$
exists. Then
$$ f'(x) $$
exists?. In other words, is the following implication true?
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} \ \text{exists} \implies f'(x) \ \text{exists} $$

I think that it's not necessarily true, but I haven't found a counterexample. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice question. To get some insight, consider the fact that nothing here is assumed about $f(x)$. So this could be anything.

Comment: Try $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$.

Comment: The characteristic function of $\Bbb{Q}\subset\Bbb{R}$ has a symmetric derivative at every rational, but $f$ is discontinuous everywhere…